# Daily schedule local notification at particular time in ios 11 objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have to schedule a local notification at a particular time in a daily basis , i have done with some code but the notification coming many times 
Thanks in advance

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound;

    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!granted) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
            center.delegate = self;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
        }
        else
        {

            [self scheduleLocalNotifications];
        }


    }];
}
```

the function call is

```
- (void)scheduleLocalNotifications 
 {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:now];
[components setHour:8];
 [components setMinute:00];
[components setSecond:00];
// Gives us today's date but at 9am
NSDate *next8am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
if ([next8am timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
    // If today's 9am already occurred, add 24hours to get to tomorrow's
    next8am = [next8am dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
}
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = next8am;
notification.alertTitle = @"------App";
notification.alertBody = @"You may have new notifications...";
// Set a repeat interval to daily
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import UserNotifications

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: D 
ateComponents(hour: 20, minute: 00), repeats: true)
print(trigger.nextTriggerDate() ?? "nil")

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "title"
content.body = "body"
// make sure you give each request a unique identifier. (nextTriggerDate 
description)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identify", content: content, 
trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
if let error = error {
    print(error)
    return
}
print("scheduled")
}
```

Don't forget to ask the user permission to schedule notifications in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, 
.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
    // your code
}
return true
}
```